# How to change password without current password in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using `devise` for `authentication` and i have a `role` for each user and i allow the user with `admin` role to create new user and i want the admin user to `edit the password` for the rest of user if they forgot their password. But i cannot able to change the password without current password in edit. So how can i allow the admin user to change the password by editing the users password and save as we do for the rest of the values.

Comment: What happens when you try to change the password for another user? I jsut did it just fine using the code that i posted below.

Answer (score 12):

Since `update_without_password` still requires `current_password` to update the password, you will have to have an `update` like this:

```
  def update
    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete("password")
      params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
```

This example is meant for updating the current user (including user's password), but you can modify it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 4):

```
@user.update_attributes(password: params[:user][:password])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a method built in to devise called `update_without_password`.

Here's what I'm using in my update method:

```
 # PUT /manage_users/1
  # PUT /manage_users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    able_to_edit_profile?

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete("password")
      params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        @user.save        

        # sign the user in with their new password so it doesn't redirect to the login screen
        sign_in @user, :bypass => true

        format.html { 
          flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully updated.'
          redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)
        }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit", notice: 'Error updating user.' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private 

  # If the user is not an admin and trying to edit someone else's profile, redirect them
  def able_to_edit_profile?
    if !current_user.try(:admin?) && current_user.id != @user.id
      flash[:alert] = "That area is for administrators only."
      redirect_to :root
  end
  end
```

Comment: Actually this update_without_password can be used if we want to change other values without giving password but we cannot update password.

Comment: I have used 'if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete("password")
      params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
    end'  but with  @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) and it works now.

Comment: Ah good to know. I actually just ran into an issue last night and noticed that this code wasn't working to change a users password. I will use your solution to fix my problem. Glad we could solve both of our problems together.

Comment: I've edited my answer to use the update_attributes method and i've also added a line that shows how to re-sign the user in so they don't get redirected to the login page.